# Cause of ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError "Expression has changed after it was checked"

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I checked some documents but I could not understand the cause of this error in my situation. Although it loooks great article :  https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/  , I could not understand.

Let me give my details on code.

**.html**

```
<mat-tab-group>


    <mat-tab label="My Cards">
      <div class="cardList">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let card of myCards; let i=index">
          <app-card [cardItem]="card" 
                     class="cardListItem"></app-card>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Winning Cards">
      <div class="cardList">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let winningCard of winningCards; let i=index">
          <app-card [cardItem]="winningCard" 
                     class="cardListItem"></app-card>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

For below codes,
`somefunction()` is called from `ngOnInit()` and `this.myCards` is full before usage

**.ts (FORMAT 1)**

```
//fill myCards and winningCards

somefunction
{  ..........
   this.winningCards= [...this.myCards];
}
```

**got error "Expression has changed after it was checked"**

**.ts (FORMAT 2)**

```
//fill myCards and winningCards

somefunction
{   ..........
    const myClonedArray: CardModel[] = Object.assign([], this.myCards);
    this.winningCards = myClonedArray;
}
```

**got error "Expression has changed after it was checked"**

**.ts (FORMAT 3)**

```
//fill myCards and winningCards
somefunction
{       ..........
        this.winningCards = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myCards));
}
```

**I DO NOT GET ERROR, WORKING FINE**

so if you consider this codes, why this error occured while I was using 
`[...this.myCards];` or  `Object.assign([], this.myCards);` and not occured while I was using  `this.winningCards = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.usedCards));`

Comment: Q.1. where is somefunction is being called from? Q.2. where are this.myCards and this.usedCards being initialized? Q.3. In format 1 and format 2 you are using this.myCards but in format 3 you are using this.usedCards, is that correct?

Comment: @ysf, I edited question, I mistakely wrote used cards, I am using this.myCards in all versions

Comment: in format 1 and format 2 this.winningCards contains same object references within this.myCards. in format 3 new objects gets created. so my guess is some of those references gets changed within app-card. or in ngOnInit() something similar happens.

Comment: @ ysf   In format 1 and 2 I am copying too.  I could not understand the issue. I neither understand the reason of error  nor  the difference of Json.parse between other copying methods. 2 issue that I could not sort out

Comment: copying may not always be copying :) please take a look at this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Comment: ysf I know this issue, but more thing to need investigate in here , because error was about a field in cardItem object.(fırst level field , not nested field)

Comment: if the problem is in cardItem object my guess is probably correct. can you share code for ngOnInıt and app-card component. a stackblitz demo would be much better.